# Select two data in database - CodeIgniter3

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have a problem with extracting data from the database.

My application is based on CodeIgniter 3 and AngularJS.

I have two tables in my database:

1) domains
2) organic search

In domains and organic_search, I have view_id columns - which are related to each other.

**My problem:** I connect to the database, when I go to a given domain URL, I get the domain ID (from the table domains), however, the data from the organic_search table is not collected. I have no idea how to connect the domains.iD relationship with domains.viewId = organic_search.viewId.

Below my code:

Controller domains.php

```
{
    $this->load->model('admin/analytics_model');
    $result = $this->analytics_model->get_by_domain_id($id);
    echo '{"records":' . json_encode( $result ) . '}';
}
```

Controller analytics.php

```
public function index($id = false)
{
    $result = $this->analytics_model->get($id);
    echo '{"records":' . json_encode( $result ) . '}';
}
```

Model analytics_model.php

```
public function get_by_domain_id($id)

{
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $q = $this->db->get('organic_search');
        $q = $q->result();

        return $q;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`Join`](http://www.sql-join.com/)

```
$this->db->join('domains AS d', 'd.viewId = o.viewId'); 
$this->db->where('o.id', $id);
return $this->db->get('organic_search AS o')->result();
```

Comment: I corrected your code on:

$ this-> db-> where ('d.id', $ id);